# ” Renderscript Allocation copyto “ cost time a lot, how to solve it?

Tags: android, renderscript

```
void sobel(const uchar * v_in , uchar4 *v_out, const void * userData , uint32_t x , uint32_t y)
{
    if ((x==0)||(x==width-1)||(y==0)||(y==height-1)) return;

    uchar a00 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x-1,y-1); 
    uchar a01 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x,y-1);
    uchar a02 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x+1,y-1);
    uchar a10 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x-1,y);
    uchar a11 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x,y);
    uchar a12 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x+1,y);
    uchar a20 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x-1,y + 1);
    uchar a21 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x,y + 1);
    uchar a22 = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gIn,x+1,y + 1);


    short ux = ((short)((a20) * (1) + (a21) * (2) + (a22) * (1) + (a00) * (-1) + (a01) * (-2) + (a02) * (-1)));
    short uy = ((short)((a02) * (1) + (a12) * (2) + (a22) * (1) + (a00) * (-1) + (a10) * (-2) + (a20) * (-1)));

    uchar resx = (NDA_CAST_8U(ux));
    uchar resy = (NDA_CAST_8U(uy));

    //outdata[y*width + x] = resx;

    rsSetElementAt_uchar(gUx,resx,x,y);
    rsSetElementAt_uchar(gUy,resy,x,y);

    uchar res  = 255 * (uchar)(ux > 10 || uy > 10 );
    *v_out = (uchar4){res,res,res,255};
}
```

I'm confused about renderscript. I just want use it to do Imageprocess `sobel (image size : 640 * 480`; I tried to use JNI to do `sobel`, but it takes 3.5ms, which is too long. Frame-per-frame, with the byte data I get from camera `surfaceview`, I find that, whether I code or use the api `ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3`, the copyto and copyfrom operation take a lot of time (about 15ms). I'm wondering why the allocation is so slow and what I can do about this.

Comment: CopyTo and CopyFrom as the name suggests is copying data from renderscript memory to Java memory. I think I saw faster copies and I was dealing with larger buffers (approx ~13 MP). The way you defined your allocation could matter... meaning the type of element the allocation is made of. Can you post how you define your allocation as well? Also which device are you using? Can you try on Nexus 5 and report the numbers as well?

Comment: @maxpayne Thanks for your answer， here it is how i define my allocation , 'Type.Builder tbIn = new Type.Builder(_renderScript,
    Element.U8(_renderScript));
  tbIn.setX(w);
  tbIn.setY(h);
  // tbIn.setZ(1);
  tbIn.setMipmaps(false);
  tbIn.setFaces(false);

  Type.Builder tb_ux = new Type.Builder(_renderScript,
    Element.U8(_renderScript));
  tb_ux.setX(w);
  tb_ux.setY(h);
  // tbTmp.setZ(1);
  tb_ux.setMipmaps(false);
  tb_ux.setFaces(false);

' i try to set pointers in rs file , want it does any copy , but it does not workout , i wonder how to use the result of kernel's Compute fastly

Comment: I also noticed (you can verify that with System.nanoTime(), DDMS or systrace) that copyTo is taking much more time than a heavy computational function. The size of the array and/or the type of element inside did not really helped when I changed them.

Comment: I think copyTo is using some form of memcopy when moving data. Any comparisons on CopyTo performance without tagging the performance with the max CPU clock frequency of the device is useless. I also think, the performance varies depending on whether you are using 1D, 2D or 3D type of allocations. 1D allocations would be sequential memory allocations where as 2D and 3D allocations could have their data at different places in memory. So copies could be usually slower for 2D and 3D

Answer (score 4):

That's actually your computation that takes this time and not copyTo. 
Computation is executed in background and only when you try to access the result (using copyTo) you need to wait for the computation to finish.

When you call your script.forEach_sobel it erturns almost instantly, but this doesn't mean that the computation is already completed, it's running in background.

You can check actual time of copyTo by just commenting out script.forEach_sobel call, if you don't call this method and just try to use copyTo then it will be much faster.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The forEach* calls are blocking calls and do not return until the work is done.  It is forwarding the work on to either background threads or other processor (GPU), but the thread calling forEach* blocks to wait for the computation to be completed.

Comment: Are you sure about it @LarrySchiefer? Is there some specification for this? My experience is different, at least when running on Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4. Simple timing with System.nanotime shows that forEach* takes only around 20 micro seconds, and then copyTo takes 15 millis, but if I just comment out forEach then copyTo takes 300 micro seconds. The only reasonable explanation for this is that forEach is actually async.

Comment: forEach* performs its operations async on bg threads (or another processor), but looking at the framework code itself (for the CPU implementation) shows it blocks.  In the C++ framework code, RsdCpuScriptImpl::invokeForEach() is called, which calls mCtx->launchThreads(), which sets up threads and finally does this:

`
while (__sync_fetch_and_or(&mWorkers.mRunningCount, 0) != 0) {
        mWorkers.mCompleteSignal.wait();
    }
`

before it returns. The likely reason for your timing is because the RS engine knows nothing has changed in the allocation, so there's nothing to actually copy.

Comment: Even if allocation wasn't changed then copyTo needs to execute the copy because I copy the data to different destination (other bitmap).
I did another test, modified the renderscript code to execute the same operation 10 time (added for loop around the whole function). And now the times are: forEach - 20 micro seconds, coptyTo - 50 millis. This clearly shows that computation in renderscript kernel influence the time of copyTo and not the time of forEach.
I understand that you checked the code, but maybe my device uses different one.

Comment: It's possible that the newer N5 images are using a post-processing barrier since they utilize an on-board GPU (the QCom Adreno).  But, it's also possible that the copyTo is still optimized: if the forEach was never run and therefore the allocation was never transferred to the on-board GPU then there's no data to marshall back across the interface and copyTo would be faster if forEach was never executed.  Memory copying and marshalling is very slow compared to computation, particularly if it has to work with another processor.

Comment: To force a blocking wait until the processing is finished, call `_renderScript.finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

I [have found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63962361/192373) that `Allocation.copyTo()` may take significant time if renderscript is scheduled for execution on GPU, and is immediate when scheduled for execution on CPU. But on GPU, the `forEach()` was asynchronous (@Larry Schiefer), and at first I thought that GPU execution was even shorter. Luckily, *[AccoGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7335974/accoguy)* timely [corrected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63962361/custom-renderscript-is-slower-than-intrinsic?noredirect=1#comment113266736_63962361) me.